# Change Java application icon?

Tags: java, icons

Does anyone know how to change the default java application app icon? I am using a mac if it makes a difference. Any ideas are good!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;

class JFrameTest
{
    public static void main(String _[])
    {
        JFrame jFrame = new JFrame("Hello World!!");
        jFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jFrame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon("c:/home/ravi/creampink.png").getImage());
        jFrame.setSize(400,400);
        jFrame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Just search for Download 128X128 icon in google to get some sample icons

Answer (score 4):

You can use [JFrame.setIconImage](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setIconImage%28java.awt.Image%29).

Here is an [example](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/223.html).

Haven't seen any issues on the mac.

Comment: Have posted link to an example.

Answer (score 1):

The JFrame.setIconImage is where you want to work. It seems to be working on all operating systems.

Answer (score 0):

Place the icon in your resources folder (`src/main/resources` for a Maven project with default settings, or alongside the main window class file for an Eclipse project with default settings). (The accepted example uses a hard-coded path in the file system—that is OK in a lab setting, but will break on deployment.)

Assuming `theWindow` is the main window of your application, do the following:

```
theWindow.setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(
    ClassLoader.getSystemResource("someicon.png")));
```

If you are subclassing `JFrame`, you can do this in the constructor (in that case, drop the `theWindow.` prefix).