# How do I upload my Application with my own Icon and not Jar File Default Icon?

Tags: java, windows, jar, icons, executable

I've created a Java Application kind of like Notepad, I created a jar file, I did not want the icon to be the default Java Jar Icon, so I uploaded a icon.ico so the Icon would appear in Taskbar,Desktop, and also at the top-left of the application, when I run it, it works fine. I created an installer and uploaded it online so I can download it from my other computer and try it, when I download it the App works fine, but the icons do not show up, it shows the default Jar File Icon in the taskbar and top-left of application, but in the desktop it shows the Icon that I choose. Anyone knows do I have to upload anything with the Installer.exe Folder or? Thank you in advance.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Change Java application icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923571/change-java-application-icon)

Comment: Jar files can currently not hold icons for this. You needs native wrapper

Comment: I don't think that this icon can be changed individually at all. This icon belongs to all _jar_ files and depends only on the one application, that can handle this sort of files. To change Your application icon do what Kaneda suggests.

Comment: Just to be absolutely clear about this:  Are you asking about the *window icon* that appears in the corner of the title bar when the application is running, as well as in the task bar?  Or are you asking about the icon for the .jar file itself that appears on the desktop and in file browsers, even when the application is not running?

Comment: @VGR I am asking about the icons at the top-left and in the task bar as well, I need it to be my personalized one, not he default JAR.file icon. It is kinda hard to explain it in words, but I think you got the idea. Please let me know if I can explain in any other type of way. Thank you!

Comment: @Kaneda , actually no. The thing is that particular icon belongs in someone else's PC, so when I use that particular code, the image will not display in my PC because I do not have that resource of image/icon, that is my issue. I am not sure how do I transfer it so it works on other peoples PC as well. Thank you for your response, but I will look deeper into this! Thanks!

Comment: Place your icon image file inside your .jar when you build, and read it in your code using [Class.getResource](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/16/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Class.html#getResource(java.lang.String)).  That will guarantee the icon is available on every system.